# Local Storage in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, javascript-framework

I have the following code .I want to load the test model in my local storage but the value field in my browser is empty.

```
Ext.regModel('test', {
            fields: [{name:'ii',type:'int'},{name:'query',type:'string'}],
              proxy: {
              type: 'localstorage',
              id  : 'testuser'
                     }
            });
            var store=new Ext.data.Store({
            model:'test',
            data:[{ii:'21',query:'g' }]
            });
            store.add({ii:'21'},{query : 'q'});
            store.load();
            store.sync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the proxy parameter under the  Ext.data.Store

ie code should be changed to

```
Ext.regModel('test', {
            fields: [{name:'ii',type:'int'},{name:'query',type:'string'}],

            });
            var store=new Ext.data.Store({
            model:'test',
            proxy: {
              type: 'localstorage',
              id  : 'testuser'
                     }
            data:[{ii:'21',query:'g' }]
            });
```

Now try it?